# Installing new packages in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, installation, meteor

I have deployed meteor on my local Linux machine with `curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh`. Now I would like to install this: https://github.com/gmanricks/Meteor-Schedule-Example - what is the correct way to do this? I would like the final effect like it's here: http://schedule.meteor.com/

Or maybe you know any other ready solutions like this? I would like to have schedule maintained via web browser. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't deployed anything. You have just installed meteor on your local machine. 
You are going the right path, now you need to clone the repository so pop open the console and type:

```
git clone https://github.com/gmanricks/Meteor-Schedule-Example.git
```

That will create a directory so you cd into it and type

```
meteor run
```

and there you have the app working locally, now if you want to deploy to meteor servers you can do:

```
meteor deploy meteor-scheduele-or-whatever.meteor.com
```

Best regards.